# Is it possible to have an iOS app that's not ARC enabled but with some arc files?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

Is it possible to have an iOS app that's not ARC enabled but with some arc files?

I have a non-ARC enabled app where I would like to bring in some ARC enabled files. Is this possible?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Comment: my question is that but in reverse. how do I move an ARC enabled file into a non-ARC project. thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `-fobjc-arc` flag to enable ARC for specific files.

Comment: the compiler says 'unrecognized command line option for -f-objc-arc '. fyi - I'm trying to move some sample ARC compliant code into a non-ARC app. thanks

Comment: Looks like there isn't supposed to be a hyphen between f and objc.  Edited my answer.

Comment: I still get: cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-fobjc-arc" thanks again

Comment: @hanumanDev That is the correct way, after searching it.  I feel silly for not assuming it existed :p.  Where are you adding the line?

Comment: Here's the solution to this error: You are using the wrong compiler. Go to Target Settings > Build Settings > Build Options, and change the compiler from `LLVM GCC` to `Apple LLVM`. Build and run, and the problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

Using the `-fobjc-arc` flag to enable `ARC` for specific files may result in an `'unrecognized command line option for -f-objc-arc` error which is because of using the wrong compiler.

To fix this, go to `Target Settings > Build Settings > Build Options`, and change the compiler from `LLVM GCC` to `Apple LLVM`. Build and run, and the problem should be solved.